# Query Rails Postgres with array data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

So, Ive been trying to query my PostgreSQL model in Rails, but get the following error:

> undefined method `id' for TransactionTemplate::ActiveRecord_Relation

My code:

```
    @transaction_templates = TransactionTemplate.where("transaction_category_id = 1")
    @transaction = Transaction.where("transaction_template_id in (?)", @transaction_templates.id)
```

I know that the transaction templates is an array and that there is therefor not just one ID it needs to look up, but multiple of IDs, just as I want it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@transaction_templates = TransactionTemplate.where("transaction_category_id = 1")
@transaction = Transaction.where("transaction_template_id in (?)", @transaction_templates.map(&:id))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need just ids then try:

```
@transaction_template_ids = TransactionTemplate.where("transaction_category_id = 1").pluck(:id)
@transaction = Transaction.where("transaction_template_id in (?)", @transaction_template_ids)
```

Or you have proper associations then

```
@transaction = Transaction.joins(:transaction_template).where("transaction_category_id = 1")
```

Comment: Thanks Ansar, used dkp's answer though